# name 'plot' is not defined when using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I try to draw a graph using the following codes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = data["Passengers"]
plt.plot(x)
plot.show()
```

but it says "name 'plot' is not defined". How could I solve this question? THANKS A LOT!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOD9b.png)

Comment: `plt.show()`.....

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `plot.show()` code, it should plot fine with `plt.plot(x)` as you have already shown with the image you attach:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = data["Passengers"]
plt.plot(x)
```